# In the literature on infinite graphs, are there results on "periodizable" graphs?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, graph-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected countably infinite $k$-regular simple graph (no loops or multiple edges). For $A$ a finite subset of $V$, let me denote by $G_A=(A,E_A)$ the induced subgraph with vertex set $A$ obtained by only keeping edges with both ends in $A$. Now let me define the (inner) boundary $\partial A$ as the set of vertices in $A$ who have a (neighbor for $G$) outside $A$. This is the same as the vertices with a defect of regularity, i.e., whose degree relative to $G_A$ is $<k$.

Let me now define a *completion* $\overline{G_A}$ to be a graph with vertex set $A$ obtained from $G_A$ by adding some edges between elements of $\partial A$ while keeping vertex degrees $\le k$. Given a vertex $v$, a finite set $A$ containing $v$ and a number $c\in (0,1]$, let me say that $v$ is **$c$-movable in $A$** if there exists a completion $\overline{G_A}$ of $G_A$ such that the orbit of $v$ for the action of ${\rm Aut}(\overline{G_A})$ has size $\ge c\times |A|$.
Here ${\rm Aut}(\overline{G_A})$ is of course the automorphism group of the graph $\overline{G_A}$, and $|A|$ denotes the cardinality of $A$.

I would like to call $G$ a **periodizable graph** if it satisfies the following property:

*For every $v\in V$ there is a constant $c_v\in (0,1]$ and an increasing sequence $A_n$ of finite sets containing $v$ such that $\cup A_n=V$ and such that, for every $n$, $v$ is $c_v$-movable in $A_n$.*

> **Question:** Has this notion or something approaching been studied in the literature? If so, could you please provide some references I could look up.

A trivial example of periodizable graph with $c_v=1$ is the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^d$:
take big hypercubes containing the fixed vertex $v$ and put "periodic boundary conditions".

The [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279056/cubic-almost-vertex-transitive-graphs-with-given-spanning-tree) I asked recently is about an example at the opposite end of the spectrum: the infinite 3-regular tree.  If restricting to Cayley graphs makes the question easier to connect to the available literature, that's perfectly fine. I am interested in possibly more general situations where ${\rm Aut}(G)$ could even be trivial but understanding the Cayley graph case would already be a big help.

**Addendum:** One could define an invariant of the graph I would call the *periodic movability constant* ${\rm PM}(G)$ as the supremum in $[0,1]$ of numbers $c$ for which one could do the construction above with $c_v=c$ for all vertices. I would be particularly interested in examples of graphs with $0<{\rm PM}(G)<1$ if they exist.

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly, then I think your example of the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^d$ can be vastly generalised to any Cayley graph of any finitely generated residually finite group.

Comment: Tangentially related: there is a substantial literature on a notion of 'growth in infinite graphs', which is spiritually similar to your problem. Please note, this is quite *different* from your definition, and, to me, does not even meet your "something approaching" qualification. If despite these warnings you would like to look into it, places to start on this are: Florian Lehner: *Distinguishing graphs with intermediate growth.* Combinatorica, 36 (3), pp. 333 – 347, 2016, and Johannes Cuno, Wilfried Imrich, Florian Lehner: *Distinguishing graphs with infinite motion and nonlinear growth*.

Comment: And to say something specific to your question: you might find more genuinely related to your question in the literature, and more appreciation for your definition, if you formulate a (perhaps even equivalent?) definition which *only ever speaks of the group $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$*, making one requirement or the other about it, but not use a *sequence of finite groups associated with your graph*, like you are currently doing. Maybe  it will even turn out to be rather easy to make this adjustment.

Comment: @PeterHeinig: I asked the question the way I did because that is exactly what I need for the statistical mechanics application I am studying. Thanks for the two references you mentioned.

Comment: @HJRW:Thanks that sounds encouraging. However does this work for the Cayley graph of $\langle a,b\ |\ a^2=I\rangle$ which should look like the 3-regular infinite tree? In https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279056/cubic-almost-vertex-transitive-graphs-with-given-spanning-tree?noredirect=1&lq=1 the answers I got show it is impossible to achieve $c=1$, at least with the $A_n$ being balls centered at $v$. Would you mind elaborating on your argument using the residually finite property in an answer.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam: on reflection, I was a bit hasty.  Cayley graphs of residually finite groups have the property that any finite subgraph embeds into the Cayley graph of a finite quotient. But I now realize that your condition additionally requires this embedding to be surjective on vertices.   Perhaps it's also worth mentioning that your condition is faintly reminiscent of *soficity* (though certainly stronger if you have an example of a graph that doesn't satisfy it!).

Comment: @HJRW: Thanks for your last comment. I was indeed thinking about what you said on the simplest example of the free group on two elements and trying to use $A_n$'s that are fundamental domains for a decreasing sequence of finite index subgroups but didn't get anywhere. One of the issues is that it seemed $v$ had to be in the boundary and this prevented the $A_n$'s to cover the whole space. We just hired an expert in sofic groups so I might ask him. Thanks for pointing out this connection.