# Graphs with high girth and low diameter

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, geometric-group-theory, extremal-graph-theory, groupoids

As the title says, I'm interested in graphs with high girth and low diameter.

Given a class $\Gamma$ of finite $k$-regular graphs, call a $\Gamma$-graph  GD-extremal if every $\Gamma$-graph either has strictly lower girth, or strictly higher diameter, or exactly the same value for both.

Finding graphs which are GD-extremal in arbitrary $\Gamma$ seems very hard, but I'm wondering if that might change for particular choices of $\Gamma$. For example, fix $k = 3$ and let $\Gamma$ be the class of vertex-transitive (optionally, symmetric and/or Cayley) graphs. Could there be some relevant group(oid) theory that makes things more manageable?

Comment: Are there nontrivial examples where diameter = 1/2 girth?

Comment: I'm not sure what you'd consider trivial, but: the complete bipartite graph on 6 nodes has girth 4 and diameter 2, the Heawood graph has girth 6 and diameter 3, and the Tutte-Coxeter graph has girth 8 and diameter 4. If we count non-vertex-transitive graphs, the Tutte 12-cage has girth 12 and diameter 6. No larger examples are known, but I'm happy for girth to be only moderately higher than diameter if the graph is extremal.

Comment: Building theory has examples of graphs with diameter = 1/2 girth, e.g., generalized n-gons have diameter n and girth 2n - see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_polygon

Comment: Indeed, but there seem to be only boundedly many of these for any fixed degree. Edit: in case this was a response to my "no larger examples are known" above, my apologies - I was referring specifically to cubic examples. In general I think it's been conjectured that there are finitely many for any given degree (but don't quote me on that).

Comment: possibly related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279056/cubic-almost-vertex-transitive-graphs-with-given-spanning-tree

Comment: Does [Marston Conder's list of symmetric graphs](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~conder/symmcubic10000list.txt) help?

Comment: @LeechLattice Yes, thank you. I went through the list and found the following extremal graphs: tetrahedron 4.1, |aut| = 24, girth 3, diameter 1; Petersen 10.1, 120, 5, 2; Heawood 14.1, 336, 6, 3; Tutte-Coxeter 30.1, 1440, 8, 4; 60.1, 360, 9, 5; 162.1, 486, 12, 7; 168.1, 504, 12, 7; 1250.2, 15000, 16, 10; 4324.1, 51888, 19, 14; 5456.1, 32736, 19, 14.

Comment: Many but not all of the automorphism group sizes are consistent with being simple and non-abelian, which is not surprising since (I believe) high girth relative to graph size implies expansion, and e.g. a family of Cayley graphs is known to be expanders only if the corresponding groups are perfect. Presentations of the groups are given, but I don't know enough about groups to easily check. Either way, having examples is nice but by itself doesn't tell me much about the general situation - e.g. how could I have found these (or at least narrowed down the candidates) without the list?